# Error while connecting to localhost in mongoDB compass

Tags: mongodb, localhost, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to connect to my localhost server but i keep getting the message:

> An error occurred while loading navigation: unable to open cursor at URI statistics:table:collection-12--1005878804071058643. reason: No such file or directory

I tried mongod repair, and I change the data path trying to fix it. The thing is that I really don't care about backups or anything. I just need it working for tests in my code.

I tried reinstall it but i keep getting the same message. I thought it would just forget it and get the new location, but it seems it keeps going to the same place and looking for the same file, over and over again.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So, i think i found a way out.

I opened terminal and executed mongod. I found a warning there "Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted". So I 'sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock' and after that 'sudo service mongod start' to restart mongod service. But it doesn't work.

I went after mongodb-27017.sock and i found that it wasn't in tmp.
Then I executed mongod and I received a SocketException saying that the address was already in use.

Then, I executed 'sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P' and killed mongod process, because it was executing in port 27017 somehow.

After that I executed 'mongod' again and everything was back to normal.